# How to make notice when image gets uploaded with Paperclip

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Is there any way to include a notice on a page like "Successfully Uploaded" when image gets uploaded with Paperclip?

Avatar upload is part of my simple form here is a current code:

```
<div class="img-circle">
         <%= profile_avatar_select(@user) %>
    </div>
    <%= f.input :avatar, as: :file, label: "false" %>
      </div>
```

my application_helper.rb

```
def profile_avatar_select(user)  
  return image_tag user.avatar.url(:medium),
                   id: 'image-preview',
                   class: 'img-responsive img-circle profile-image' if user.avatar.exists?
  image_tag 'default-avatar.png', id: 'image-preview',
                                  class: 'img-responsive img-circle profile-image'
end
```

and in user.rb:

```
has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: '152x152#' }  
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/  
end
```

Comment: in controller: `flash[:success] = "Image Uploaded"`

Answer (score 1):

**application.html.erb**

```
<% flash.each do |k,v| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, v, class: "alert alert-#{k} text-center" %>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
#in a method right above render or redirect
flash[:success] = "Image Uploaded"
```

Comment: why have you not put this message to locale files.